# What's the best way to update multiple values in an array of documents using MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So I have a document in the db, which looks like this:

```
...
someArray: [{
id: string
qty: number
}]
...
```

A db query needs to update this single document and increase the value of "qty" field for those entries in the array which match certain conditions.

I know I can do this in many ways, with one (arrayFilters) or multiple queries etc. But I need to meet the following requirements:

- No other update operation must modify this document while my update is running. My understanding is that MongoDB 4.4 already guarantees this as long as I do this as a single operation (atomic updates). Is that correct?
- Each matching value must be updated or none of them should be updated. So if I can only update 2 elements of the array and a 3rd one is not updated because the condition fails, I need to revert the whole operation.

What's the best way to do that?

I mean, transactions are not useful here, since I'm updating only a single document.
Also, if an update condition fails, that's not an error, so the transaction wouldn't revert.

On the other hand, if I use multiple update operations to do this, then another update (started by another user) might modify the record and I couldn't revert.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update operations on 1 document were always atomic.

Mongodb 4.0+ added trasactions for multi-document operations, which you don't need here.

MongoDB 4.2 added pipeline updates, and with those we can do very complicated updates.But we cant mix update operators with aggregate operators, you should use aggregate operators and stages.

In your case probably a `$map` operator can do it fine, it runs for each member of the array checks those conditions and produces the updated member.

[Example1, members are numbers](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9BsXM4wLDB)

Its just an array [1,2,3] and if member>=3 it becomes "UPDATED!"

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$eq": 1
  }
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "myarray": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$myarray",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$$m",
                  3
                ]
              },
              "UPDATED!",
              "$$m"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For document members you can do it like bellow, it justs add 10 to `qty` field.
(if MongoDB 5 you can use [$setField instead $mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/))

[Example2, members are documents](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6soSyed3wlH)

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$eq": 1
  }
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "myarray": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$myarray",
          "as": "d",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$d",
              {
                "qty": {
                  "$add": [
                    "$$d.qty",
                    10
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```